# JSONDecoder erorr: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 10 column 29 (char 16011)

Tags: python, json

I am requesting URLs which contain JSON objects in python. 
Some of these URLs contain several JSON objects (so several parts which are enclosed by these brackets: [])

When I tried to load these with `json.loads()` I got the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 494 column 1 (char 50502)
```

Therefore I tried to split the JSON objects and write them into a list like this:

```
response = requests.get(url)
textinhalt = response.text
ref = textinhalt.rsplit('[')
tev = []
for line in ref:
    daten = json.loads(line[line.find(r"{"):line.rfind("}")+1]) 
    tev.append(daten)
```

But I get this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 10 column 29 (char 16011)
```

For example here is the part of the JSON that causes the Extra Data error(line 494):

```
474.    "originalbild" : {
475.       "alt" : "",
476.       "height" : "3601",
477.       "quelle" : "",
478.       "src" : "/imgs/65/2/7/6/2/8/0/4/IMG_5630-3a13bb38ae440652.jpeg",
479.       "untertitel" : "",
480.       "width" : "5401"
481.    },
482.    "b" : "",
483.    "redakteur_bid" : "",
484.    "redakteur_email" : "",
485.    "redakteur_inline" : "0",
486.    "redakteur_kategorie" : "1",
487.    "redakteur_kuerzel" : "",
488.    "redakteur_nachname" : "",
489.    "redakteur_redaktion" : "",
490.    "redakteur_vorname" : "",
491.    "ressort" : "",
492.    "seitennavigation_liste" : [
493.       {
494.          "_baseurl" : "/Macoun-2019-Von-SwiftUI-bis-NFC-4547400.html",
495.          "artikelseite" : 1,
496.          "container_id" : 4547400,
497.          "titel" : "Macoun 2019: Von SwiftUI bis NFC"
498.       },
499.       {
500.          "artikelseite" : 2,
501.          "titel" : "Motion Capturing in ARKit und RealityKit"
502.       },
503.       {
504.          "artikelseite" : 3,
505.          "titel" : "Bring deine Tests zum Rennen"
506.       },
507.       {
508.          "artikelseite" : 4,
509.          "titel" : "Tipps f\u00fcr Existenzgr\u00fcnder"
510.       },
511.       {
512.          "artikelseite" : 5,
513.          "titel" : "Cross Platform Entwicklung mit Kotlin"
514.       }
515.    ],
516.    "seo_beschreibung" : "",
517.    "seo_no_meta_description" : 0,
518.    "seo_titel" : "",
519.    "show_webdev_chooser" : null,
520.    "socialbookmarks_keywords_ph_data" : "Apple, Entwickler, Programmieren, iOS, macOS",
521.    "speakingurl_primitive" : "Macoun-2019-Von-SwiftUI-bis-NFC",
522.    "teaser_anrisstext" : "",
523.    "teaser_titel" : "",
524.    "teaser_untertitel" : "",
525.    "texte_anzahl_zeichen" : [
526.       12499
527.    ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include some of the json data with which you got the error.

Comment: The JSON you're trying to load isn't formatted correctly

Comment: @luis.parravicini Hi I added the part of the JSON which apparently causes the ```Extra Data``` Error.

Comment: What @byxor said, check line 482, that `"",` is not formatted correctly.

Comment: @luis.parravicini sorry that was my error. I copied it wrong. I edited the OP,  line 482 looks like this: "b" . " "

Comment: what do you have if you remove the underscore of the line 494 key

Comment: The json fragment you provided parses ok (I've wrapped it with curly braces to make it a hash). You should check your code as you are splitting the json and then parsing it. The error must be there. Try to parse the whole json you receive, if that can be parsed then the problem is not the json.

Comment: Hi @luis.parravicini I tried to just load it with ```json.loads()```, so without splitting it but then I am getting the ```JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 494 column 1 (char 50502)```

Comment: "Therefore I tried to split the JSON objects and write them into a list like this:"  Please don't.  If it's valid JSON then the JSON parser will work.  Chances are it isn't but what you've posted is valid thus far so.

Comment: How are you requesting the data and returning JSON?  Your problem is more likely there.  FWIW the famed [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module will handle returning JSON from an HTTP response body for you: `import requests; response = requests.get('https://example.com'); print(response.json())`